# releasing the scrollview back to the beginning and I can not fill the textfield final

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I have a scrollview with a list of data to fill, as a form, when under the scroll to fill the data that are not working but when you release the selection is up and I can not do anything, what I want is that no matter where you release the scroll stand there.
this is in the viewDidLoad()

```
[scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)];
```

have dealt with these lines of code but do not work
this is a video whit the problem:
http://youtu.be/jFQSnz08nPo

another video http://youtu.be/i5h5osSoGNM

an image:
[image: an image]

Comment: It seems to me that the scroll view frame size is incorrect. Seems that it is scrolling, but it is just hidden behind the view at the bottom. Can you show some more code regarding the size of your scroll view and the positioning of the view at the bottom?

Comment: this is the same video but I put a backcolor to the scrollview http://youtu.be/i5h5osSoGNM

Comment: Are you using auto-layout? If you do, try turning it off and see if it helps.

Comment: I can not remove the auto-layout since the app is designed so as to be compatible with iPhone and iPad, there is no other way to fix it?

Comment: Can you show more code that regarding the placement of the items?

Comment: I got a picture with constrains

Comment: Maybe the height is incorrect. try removing the height constrain and instead, create a constrain from the bottom of the scroll view to the bottom bar.

Comment: btw- where in your code did you put the code the set the content size and enables scrolling?

Comment: thanks for everything, apparently due to the constraints, but now the problem is that does not work on IOS 7.x, 8.x works perfect on IOS, which can be the error?